# Getting Correct Edition of Office 2007 from Serial Key

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I have been asked by a client to refresh one of their machines.

To do this I managed to get Windows XP Setup to run in Repair mode, and while in setup I ran a serial key grabber, which grabbed the key for Office 2007.

The only thing is that the key grabber didn't tell me what edition of Office 2007 was installed.

I have acquired a number of ISOs for the different editions (Home & Student, Standard, Professional, Ultimate) but the key doesn't work in any of them.

Is there a way to get the edition from the Serial Key, or is there a generic ISO that will install any edition depending on the Serial Key?

Just to be clear:
I couldn't boot the laptop into XP when I got it, and had to use the getting to command prompt in the second part of the XP setup to run the key grabber, Belarc wouldn't run.

I have now done a clean install of XP. I didn't realise that the Office disks were for only a certain edition.

Comment: You could gather the version number from a dll in the Program Files folder, but I have no idea if it also gives info on the Edition of Office...

Comment: I cant get to the file now, as the HDD has been wiped and XP clean installed

Answer (score 2):

Office like most of Microsoft products, comes in an OEM version and a retail version and an enterprise version.  The key from one version can't work in another.

First question - ask your client - did Office come with this machine when they purchased it?  If so, most likely it was a OEM version and you have an OEM key.  You need to get the OEM iso.  If it was preloaded, see if they have the original disks.  Check the casing for a COA sticker.

Second question - did they install it after?  If so, again ask for the disk.  See if any other computers at the same time were loaded - if so, may be same version.

If this is a large company, they may have a enterprise version - if so they usually have a special key and special install disks or downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Run a [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) to create a profile of the computer

This will give you information on all the (important) installed software on the computer + Microsoft licenses.

[Example:](http://cccgc.net/Belarc/2007JuneBelarc.htm)

> - Belarc - Advisor
> - Microsoft - Internet Explorer
> - Microsoft - Money 2004
> - **Microsoft - Office Professional Edition 2003**
> - Microsoft - WebFldrs XP
> - Microsoft - Windows Defender
> - Microsoft - Windows XP Professional
> - Microsoft - Works 2000

Comment: When i got the computer the XP Setup was corrupted, so i tried to run a repair, which wouldnt finish correctly (it couldnt find drivers for the DVD Drive, so could finish installing) but i used the Shift+F10 trick to get into Command Prompt, and got it to run a Key Grabber, Belarc Advisor wouldnt run.

Comment: Ah I didn't get from your question that you had no way of getting into Windows properly. Perhaps you should edit your question to be more explicit about it ;-)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider putting the hard drive in another computer and load it up there.

Comment: Its too late now, i have wiped it and installed XP fresh

Comment: Then I suggest contacting Microsoft with the key to request for which version it is.

Comment: I might have to do that, im talking to the client to see if they know

Comment: Also might want to try Office 2007 Enterprise.